# Ag-grid checkbox render based on column data?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import ReactHighcharts from 'react-highcharts';
    import axios from 'axios';
    import { Link, browserHistory } from 'react-router';
    import { AgGridReact, AgGridColumn } from "ag-grid-react";
    import 'ag-grid/dist/styles/ag-grid.css';
    import 'ag-grid/dist/styles/ag-theme-material.css';
    class Payments extends React.Component {
        constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            this.state = {

               rowSelection: "multiple",
               columnDefs: [
                    {
                        headerName: "Paid For",
                        field: "paid_for",
                        width: 250
                    },
                    {
                        headerName: 'Amount',
                        field: 'amount',
                        width: 250
                    },
                    {
                        headerName: 'Payment Date',
                        field: 'payment_date',
                        width: 250
                    },

                    {
                        headerName: 'Reccurence',
                        field: 'recurrence_time',
                        width: 250
                    },



                    {
                        headerName: "Status",
                        field: "status",
                        checkboxSelection: true,
                        width: 250
                    },

                ],

                paymentsrequest: [],
                rowData: []
            };

        }
            onGridReady(params) {
                this.gridApi = params.api;
                this.columnApi = params.columnApi;
                this.gridApi.sizeColumnsToFit();
                window.onresize = () => {
                    this.gridApi.sizeColumnsToFit();
                }


            }


            onSelectionChanged() {
                var selectedRows = this.gridApi.getSelectedRows();

                let pendingpayments = selectedRows.filter(el => el.status == "Pending")
                let paymentsrequest = [];
                pendingpayments.forEach(function(selectedRow, index) {

                  let paymentslistobject = {
                    'payment_date': selectedRow["payment_date"],
                    'status': selectedRow["status"]
                  };
                  paymentsrequest.push(paymentslistobject);
              });

                this.setState({
                    paymentsrequest
                });

         }




        render() {
           return (
                <AgGridReact
                columnDefs={this.state.columnDefs}
                rowSelection={this.state.rowSelection}
                onGridReady={this.onGridReady.bind(this)}
                groupSelectsChildren={true}
                suppressRowClickSelection={true}
                rowData={[{paid_for: 'Plan C + B', amount: '10000',payment_date: '2018-11-14',recurrence_time: 'Quarterly',status: 'Paid'}, {paid_for: 'Plan C + B', amount: '10000',payment_date: '2018-11-14',recurrence_time: 'Quarterly',status: 'Pending'}, {paid_for: 'Plan C + B', amount: '10000',payment_date: '2018-11-15',recurrence_time: 'Quarterly',status: 'Pending'}]}                                   
                onSelectionChanged={this.onSelectionChanged.bind(this)}>

            </AgGridReact>

            )
        }
    }

    export default Payments;
```

I am using react ag-grid component and I want the input box for the status pending alone instead of all the rows, I have make use of cell-rendered but it doesnot worked,

How to render check box only for the status Pending, Check box should not be shown which has status Paid.

Solution would help me alot,

I have read all the documents but i am unable to make use of that, any one please guide me in this.

Comment: have you looked at creating custom component - https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-cell-rendering-components/#example-rendering-using-react-components

Comment: yes, I was using renderer for other things but for check box based on column data i was unable to render on particular column key data(Pending)

Comment: When you say checkbox, are you implying a check icon or a checkbox input that can respond to events?

Comment: IN THE COLUMNDEF i have kept checkboxSelection true so i am getting in all rows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should modify your `checkBoxSelection` to be a function instead of just true/false.
As per docs -

> colDef.checkboxSelection can also be a function that returns
>   true/false - use this if you want only checkboxes on some rows but not
>   others

```
                {
                    headerName: "Status",
                    field: "status",
                    checkboxSelection: function(params) {
                        return params.data.status === 'Pending'
                    },
                    width: 250
                },
```

Ag grid example [here](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-selection/#example-selection-checkbox)